# I can't catch PageError exception from Wikipedia in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, wikipedia

So, i'm making an Wikipedia cog for my discord.py bot and everything is ok if the commands are used as expected, but, if i type something wrong (like "rb!resumen sjsajsajsja"), an PageError exception appears and the code stops. I have tried so many things to catch the exception and send it to the channel or print it in the terminal, so that my bot can keep running but nothing works.

```
@commands.command()
async def resumen(self, ctx, name1, name2=None):
    if name2 is not None:
        try:
            name = name1 + " " + name2
            wiki_summary = wikipedia.summary(name, sentences=2)
            wiki_page = wikipedia.page(name)
            embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.blue(),
                                  timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
                                  title='Aquí está tu resumen:',
                                  description=f'{wiki_summary}')
            embed.add_field(name='Enlace', value=f'{wiki_page.url}',
                            inline=False)
            embed.set_footer(text='Wikipedia de Robotito',
                             icon_url=f'{bot_icon}')
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        except wikipedia.exceptions.PageError as e:
            print(e.args)
    else:
        try:
            wiki_summary = wikipedia.summary(name1, sentences=2)
            wiki_page = wikipedia.page(name1)
            embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.blue(),
                                  timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
                                  title='Aquí está tu resumen:',
                                  description=f'{wiki_summary}')
            embed.add_field(name='Enlace', value=f'{wiki_page.url}',
                            inline=False)
            embed.set_footer(text='Wikipedia de Robotito',
                             icon_url=f'{bot_icon}')
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        except wikipedia.exceptions.PageError as e:
            print(e.args)
```

This is the exception:

```
Exception has occurred: PageError
Page id "aeasjaosaopsja" does not match any pages. Try another id!
  File "/home/ticiano/Documents/RoboTito/cog/wikiarts.py", line 65, in resumen
    wiki_summary = wikipedia.summary(name1, sentences=2)
  File "/home/ticiano/Documents/RoboTito/main_bot.py", line 51, in <module>
    bot.run(token)
```

Comment: If the code you've shown us is the code you're using then it makes sense that it doesn't do anything after catching the exception - you haven't told it to. You print the exception arguments and that's the end of the function.

Comment: This is the final thing i tried to, i'm a little new to programming. So, how i can tell that i want the bot still up even if the exception raises?

Comment: With the code you've shown us the bot should stay running. It won't respond to the command because it'll go into the `except` block and thus skip the rest of the function, but it shouldn't terminate. One thing you could do is send a message back to the channel/user in the `except` block just saying "page not found" or similar.

Comment: I try to run the bot in the terminal using python main_bot.py and the bot doesn't stop when i type an incorrect command (like search asjajaj in Wikipedia), not like in VS Code where suddenly stops. Is not a solution, but a way to keep going and don't get stuck here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to "fix" this problem. The thing i was saying about that the error appears in VsCode and not in the terminal was because the terminal doesn't debug the file, simply runs it. The thing i managed to do is to keep two Wikipedia API's in the bot: **Wikipedia** for searching pages and **Wikipedia-API** for retrieving its information. So, yes, it's not a solution but is the way i took for not having this error.